# Differing AAPC and Confidence Intervals Using the Joinpoint Regression Trend Analysis Software vs R

Tags: r, regression, log-linear, segmented-regression

Let's say I have a data-set with trend data looking at an adjusted rate by year from 1980-2000, with a standard error associated with it:

```
 Year  Rate  SE
 1980  50.4  2.0
 1981  34.3  1.4
 ..
```

Let's also say I'm interested in a joinpoint (segmented) regression analysis using the Joinpoint Trend Analysis Software from the National Cancer Institute.

If the only significant joinpoint is zero, but I'm still interested in finding out the annual percentage change, isn't this the same as a weighted log-linear regression (using SE as weights)? Additionally, wouldn't the AAPC be equal to the slope * 100? So if this were to be done in R, it would look like:

```
lm(log(Rate) ~ Year, weights = SE, data))
```

The problem is the results from the Joinpoint software I listed above are NOT the same as what I am seeing in R. They are very similar, but again, not equal.

Is there something I am missing in my R model that is preventing me from replicating my results?

Answer (score 0):

You should weight by variance instead of standard error. Also, you want estimates with higher uncertainty to have lower weights. Try

`model <- lm(log(Rate) ~ Year, weights = SE ^ -2, data`

By "only significant joinpoint is zero," I assume you mean that a single line is fitted to all the data. By fitting the log rate as a response, the APC can be easily computed from the slope coefficient `b` as `100 * (exp(b) - 1)`. The APC, with confidence intervals, is most conveniently computed using the `broom` package from the `tidyverse` family.

```
library(broom)
tidy(model, conf.int = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
  mutate(across(c(estimate, conf.low, conf.high), ~ 100 * (exp(.x) - 1)))
```

The `broom` package is a convenient tool for manipulating model-fitting results.